# OS X suddenly crashed

Tags: macos, crash

Hardware Overview:

- Model Name:   MacBook Pro
- Model Identifier: MacBookPro12,1
- Processor Name:   Intel Core i5
- Processor Speed:  2.7 GHz
- Number of Processors:   1
- Total Number of Cores:  2
- L2 Cache (per Core):    256 KB
- L3 Cache:   3 MB
- Memory: 8 GB
- Boot ROM Version:   MBP121.0167.B16
- SMC Version (system):   2.28f7
- Serial Number (system): C02Q1XZHFVH3
- Hardware UUID:  B123CF3B-981B-5A57-9FB8-7CD3D36DC170

System Software Overview:

- System Version:   OS X 10.11.4 (15E65)
- Kernel Version:   Darwin 15.4.0

---

Guys, OS X suddenly crashed while I was working with Xcode, Finder. I'm not sure on what step.

Anyway, regarding this particular case.

The output from syslog:

```
4/13/16 17:17:51.095 cloudfamilyrestrictionsd[288]: CFRPushManager : connection:didChangeConnectedStatus: : 1
4/13/16 17:19:00.108 CommCenter[256]: Telling CSI to go low power.
4/13/16 17:19:00.109 AirPlayUIAgent[338]: 2016-04-13 05:19:00.109240 PM [AirPlayUIAgent] BecomingInactive: NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification
4/13/16 17:19:00.000 kernel[0]: Setting BTCoex Config: enable_2G:1, profile_2g:0, enable_5G:1, profile_5G:0
4/13/16 17:19:00.223 identityservicesd[280]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fadea74d360>: notification observer: com.apple.iChat   notification: __CFNotification 0x7fadea468c50 {name = _NSDoNotDisturbEnabledNotification}
4/13/16 17:19:00.224 imagent[309]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fa068610390>: notification observer: com.apple.FaceTime   notification: __CFNotification 0x7fa06860e530 {name = _NSDoNotDisturbEnabledNotification}
4/13/16 17:19:00.234 identityservicesd[280]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fadea74d360>:    NC Disabled: NO
4/13/16 17:19:00.248 identityservicesd[280]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fadea74d360>:   DND Enabled: YES
4/13/16 17:19:00.249 identityservicesd[280]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fadea74d360>: Updating enabled: NO   (Topics: (
))
4/13/16 17:19:00.249 imagent[309]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fa068610390>:    NC Disabled: NO
4/13/16 17:19:00.249 identityservicesd[280]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fadea43d410>: notification observer: com.apple.iChat   notification: __CFNotification 0x7fadea432ef0 {name = _NSDoNotDisturbEnabledNotification}
4/13/16 17:19:00.257 imagent[309]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fa068610390>:   DND Enabled: YES
4/13/16 17:19:00.257 imagent[309]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fa068610390>: Updating enabled: NO   (Topics: (
))
4/13/16 17:19:00.257 identityservicesd[280]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fadea43d410>:    NC Disabled: NO
4/13/16 17:19:00.262 identityservicesd[280]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fadea43d410>:   DND Enabled: YES
4/13/16 17:19:00.262 identityservicesd[280]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fadea43d410>: Updating enabled: NO   (Topics: (
))
4/13/16 17:19:01.173 cloudfamilyrestrictionsd[288]: CFRPushManager : connection:didChangeConnectedStatus: : 0
4/13/16 17:19:14.000 kernel[0]: IOPMrootDomain: idle revert, state 21
4/13/16 17:19:14.905 sharingd[270]: 17:19:14.905 : Starting AirDrop server for user 502 on wake
4/13/16 17:19:14.906 CommCenter[256]: Telling CSI to exit low power.
4/13/16 17:19:14.913 blued[87]: Can't add anymore advanced matching rule for type: 9 - capacity: 0, remaining: 0
4/13/16 17:19:14.928 blued[87]: Can't add anymore advanced matching rule for type: 9 - capacity: 0, remaining: 0
4/13/16 17:19:14.000 kernel[0]: Setting BTCoex Config: enable_2G:1, profile_2g:0, enable_5G:1, profile_5G:0
4/13/16 17:19:14.000 kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 64:66:b3:f3:01:38
4/13/16 17:19:14.000 kernel[0]: en0: channel changed to 11
4/13/16 17:19:15.027 identityservicesd[280]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fadea43d410>: notification observer: com.apple.iChat   notification: __CFNotification 0x7fadea772b20 {name = _NSDoNotDisturbDisabledNotification}
4/13/16 17:19:15.028 imagent[309]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fa068610390>: notification observer: com.apple.FaceTime   notification: __CFNotification 0x7fa068435350 {name = _NSDoNotDisturbDisabledNotification}
4/13/16 17:19:15.050 identityservicesd[280]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fadea43d410>:    NC Disabled: NO
4/13/16 17:19:15.050 imagent[309]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fa068610390>:    NC Disabled: NO
4/13/16 17:19:15.058 identityservicesd[280]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fadea43d410>:   DND Enabled: NO
4/13/16 17:19:15.058 imagent[309]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fa068610390>:   DND Enabled: NO
4/13/16 17:19:15.058 imagent[309]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fa068610390>: Updating enabled: YES   (Topics: (
    "com.apple.ess",
    "com.apple.private.ac"
))
4/13/16 17:19:15.058 identityservicesd[280]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fadea43d410>: Updating enabled: YES   (Topics: (
    "com.apple.private.alloy.icloudpairing",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.encryption",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.activity",
    "com.apple.ess",
    "com.apple.private.ids",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.phonecontinuity",
    "com.apple.madrid",
    "com.apple.private.ac",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.phone.auth",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.keychainsync",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.fmf",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.sms",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.screensharing",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.maps",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.thumper.keys",
    "com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.tethering"
))
4/13/16 17:19:15.058 identityservicesd[280]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fadea74d360>: notification observer: com.apple.iChat   notification: __CFNotification 0x7fadea772bf0 {name = _NSDoNotDisturbDisabledNotification}
4/13/16 17:19:15.063 identityservicesd[280]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fadea74d360>:    NC Disabled: NO
4/13/16 17:19:15.069 identityservicesd[280]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fadea74d360>:   DND Enabled: NO
4/13/16 17:19:15.069 identityservicesd[280]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fadea74d360>: Updating enabled: YES   (Topics: (
    "com.apple.madrid"
))
4/13/16 17:20:05.000 bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1460557205 0
```

From this output I can't figure out why the crash happened. Obviously I pressed power button and rebooted my Mac.

Any thoughts on why Mac could have hanged/crash?

Let me know if I should get another additional info.

Comment: So when you rebooted, nothing works and you get a repeatable crash?

Comment: @bmike, mac crashed just once, now everything is just fine.  I'm just wondering why that happened, wanted to dig that out.

Comment: Does a [kernel panic log](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201753) exist? This will provide the best insight into where and why your Mac encountered a kernel level bug.

Comment: @GrahamMiln, no.  Only directories/files in /Library/Logs: CrashReporter, DiagnosticReports, LKDC-setup.log.

Comment: Let's link this to our high level answers on what a panic is. If you locate your log and need help interpreting it, it would be best to start a new question narrowing the scope a bit.

Comment: This is weird, I obviously wasn't asking about the location of kernel panic log or what it is.

Comment: @sevenfourk bmike has marked this question as a duplicate because the question is unanswerable without a kernel panic log. If the panic happens again, or if a log file exists, please ask a new question. There will be visitors to this site happy to help interpret a kernel panic log.

Comment: @GrahamMiln, ok.

Comment: well, my mac crashed again, no kernel panic, no nothing.  and again it's while watching videos in safari.  funny, when you watching videos on how to swift in iOS/Mac and Mac crashes.

Comment: can it be digged in maybe any other way?